# Error when importing pylab in python 2.6.6

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, redhat

I'm trying to import `pylab` using Python 2.6.6 on REHL 6.4.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, zipfile,glob, shutil,time,scipy,numpy,matplotlib
from pylab import *
```

I get the error:

```
# ./script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pylab import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 247, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pyplot import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 78, in <module>
    new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, show = pylab_setup()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 25, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtkagg.py", line 10, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk import gtk, FigureManagerGTK, FigureCanvasGTK,\
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 8, in <module>
    import gtk; gdk = gtk.gdk
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    _init()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 52, in _init
    _gtk.init_check()
RuntimeError: could not open display
```

All of `scipy`, `numpy` and `matplotlib` are installed but I still can't import `pylab`. Is there a problem in the way I'm importing `pylab`?

Comment: That's the entire error message?

Comment: You seem to be missing the most crucial line of the traceback - the actual error.

Comment: my bad . full error message is added now

Comment: it seams you have problem with GTK module. But I think it is not full error message - you miss few last lines.

Answer (score 0):

fixed using :

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```